# Point Domain name to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, nameservers

I have a domain name registered with tmdhosting.com. And I have created a WordPress multisite setup on AWS using bitnami WordPress multisite stack.

Now I would like to point my domain name from my registrar to my AWS instance. Where they are asking me to provide them with a NS. I am new to AWS and I am not sure as to how to go about doing this.

Also did a little bit of research where it said that I will need a Route 53 (which is not free) I would want to know if there is another way to do this.

Can I use CloudFront to do this as with my previous provider had given me a cloudflare name server.

Please let me know the steps as to how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

To point a Domain Name to an EC2 instance, you can either use Route 53 or your own DNS service. In both cases:

- Assign an **Elastic IP address** to your EC2 instance
- In Route 53 or your own DNS service, define a domain/subdomain that points to this IP address

The above assumes that you wish to point to a single EC2 instance. If you have multiple instances with a Load Balancer in front, you will require a CNAME record pointing to the DNS name of the Load Balancer. (If using Route 53, using the "ALIAS" button to point to a Load Balancer.)

Route 53 is not free, but it is very cheap. If correctly configured to point to AWS resources, it can cost only 50c/month per hosted zone.

CloudFront is a content distribution network that caches web content. It will not assist you in assigning a Domain Name to an EC2 instance. (Custom domain names *can* be used with CloudFront, but that doesn't appear to be your particular question.)