# Point Cloudflare to AWS EC2 server without using route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns, cloudflare

I am trying to point Cloudflare DNS into Amazon's AWS EC2 server, but am unable to do so. When I set this up, the request to go into my url simply times out.

Based on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035892/point-domain-name-to-aws-ec2-instance), I have tried the steps (except using route53) but the subdomain still cannot not be accessed. tracert shows the request timed out half way.

How can I successfully point Cloudflare to AWS EC2 server without using route53?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to the previous question you linked to, Route53 is not required. You can configure either Route53 or your own DNS service, such as CloudFlare.

Are you able to connect directly to the public IP of your EC2 instance? Is your EC2 instance in a security group that prevents CloudFlare from connecting to it?

Comment: thank you Francis! actually i have accessed the security group but didnt realize that it was by default close all undefined port. now i have add new rule for http and https and now its working.

Answer (score 3):

Cloudflare explains how to do this here.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020991331

You add a CNAME record at Cloudflare to your AWS hostname, the URL that looks like this: my-cool-cachepp-1344276401.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare is an [authoritative DNS provider](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/), you have absolutely no need for another DNS provider like Route53.

Instead you [set the nameservers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Step-2-Create-a-CloudFlare-account-and-add-a-website) which CloudFlare issued you at your domain registrar.

You will need to enter in your existing DNS records at your DNS registrar into CloudFlare for any DNS records you wish to migrate:

[image: CloudFlare DNS options]